# How materialized view works in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to know how MV works when i insert batch with 10000 records.

How many times MV will work ?
1 time for all records or 10000 time?

And if another client insert in the same time what will happen?

Can anyone explain the mechanism.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general 1 time per insert.

Mat. view never reads a base table.
Every insert propagates inserted block into MV.

https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

https://youtu.be/ckChUkC3Pns?t=9326